# Is there a way to enable window borders in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, window-manager, customization

Window borders have been disabled in Ubuntu 14.04 by default. This can be distracting when there are overlapping console windows.  Is there a way to enable them, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The default theme in Ubuntu doesn't show borders, but you can enable borders by installing a theme that offers window borders. Use `unity-tweak-tool` to switch themes. For instance, the High Contrast theme draws a black border.